# ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS" - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, postgresql, statements

I received a SQL script from my teacher and I am getting the ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS" keyword.  Here is the statement it's saying has an error:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.businessrule_businessrulekey_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

He has it up for the entire class and it worked for everyone else.  What on earth could this be?  We are using PostgreSQL by the way.

Comment: Try without 'AS'

Comment: The class has Postgres 10 or 11, while yours is older. I think it's unfair.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use AS keyword. Try:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.businessrule_businessrulekey_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

Online compiler:
https://rextester.com/JQOR2492